# What was the general contemporary reaction to Wesley Crusher as a character?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I know that I ***hate*** Wesley Crusher from *Star Trek: The Next Generation*.  He is by far the most annoying character in my opinion.  I've also heard from others that he wasn't very well liked.  The [Memory Alpha page on Wesley](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Wesley_Crusher#Appendices) provides this quote:

> Wesley Crusher also has the distinction of being one of sci-fi's most
>   hated characters. **In a poll done by Maxim magazine only Star Wars' Jar
>   Jar Binks topped Crusher's level of annoyance. Fans expressed
>   annoyance that Wesley always seemed to be the one to save the
>   Enterprise**

My question is, when *TNG* was *airing*, **what was the general reaction to Wesley as a character?**  If it was a negative reaction, **was this the reason for Wesley's departure at the beginning of season 4?**

Comment: I can tell you that, although I never watched the show - not even once - and I knew nothing about it, I was aware that there was an annoying character played by Wil Wheaton. The only thing I knew about the series was that everyone hated Wil Wheaton's character, and I didn't even know the character's name.

Comment: I think the vitriol directed at the character was largely responsible for killing his career, which had previously seemed to be very promising, especially after *Stand By Me*.  Now he's primarily known for the TNG role, *Stand By Me* (which he did when he was like 11 years old), and for playing himself on *Big Bang Theory*.

Comment: @WadCheber I don't think that's fair to say. Wheaton has had a diverse and very successful career, but little of it has been as *broadly* successful as TNG. It's the same problem Mark Hamill has

Comment: @JasonBaker - It's only my opinion, but the promise shown by his performance in *Stand By Me* was never really fulfilled, and I suspect that this is due to the criticism he attracted during his work on TNG.  I am not aware of him being involved in any successful movies in the past 20 years or so.  The closest he got to a big movie during that time period is A minor role in *Flubber*.  Being a small part of a rebooted Jerry Lewis movie is not something to write home about.

Comment: He isn't a train wreck on the order of Corey Feldman, but he also isn't as successful as Jerry O'Connell, and no one expected Jerry O'Connell to be successful.  :)

Comment: Jar Jar is by several orders of magnitude a greater train wreck. -comment by who watched TNG as it aired (as an adolescent). Wesley was disappointing; Binks was {description will not fit, nor would it contain appropriate discourse} [a disaster].

Comment: Seriously, start to type "Shut up, Wesley" into Google and see how few characters are needed to get it to complete...

Comment: Searching Google tells you what people think NOW. Want to know what people thought in the 90s? Read through the old archives of alt.wesley.crusher.die.die.die.

Comment: Anecdotally: IIRC, Wheaton's acting as Crusher was rather stiff and forced; bad acting turns me off of movies and TV. It does not surprised me to hear/read that he wasn't a well received character.

Comment: Personally, I think Ruby Rhod tops both Jar Jar and Wesley Crusher in terms of annoyingness.

Comment: FWIW, I actually always liked Wesley. But that could just be because I was only about 6 years old at the time, and so I would have been more interested in him as the youngest crew member. That, and the fact that he was clearly very intelligent, but somewhat lacking in social skills, and that his interest in sharing his often obscure knowledge was usually seen as impetuousness, all of which reflected myself at that age.

Comment: It was more a case of writing than Wheaton's acting. He was often treated as the naive kid who required an explanation for the simplest things, but then they would turn around and have him be this genius who blew the adults away with his intelligence. And the two didn't combine well. And actually, he only saved the ship in like six episodes. Not that many, really.

Comment: I was 15 when ST:TNG first aired. I don't recall being annoyed at the Wesley Crusher character. There was lots of sci-fi in the 80s featuring naive but gifted teenagers (eg, *The Last Starfighter*) so WC was in keeping with the times. I *did* think no respectable teenager would wear WC's weird sweater ensembles, or skin-tight pants with the waistband sticking out. :)

Comment: @Omegacron IIRC there were like two or three _in a row_ (or at least in very close succession), as a result of a writers' strike (they were planning one "Wesley Episode", had everyone submit scripts for it, and then the strike started so they couldn't get any new scripts) - contributing to a perception that it happened a lot.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this, and never disliked him as a character myself. I do however find the sort of people who dwell on hating a character intolerably annoying, though.

Comment: I hated Wesley, but I *enjoyed* hating Wesley.  Q, on the other hand...

Comment: I did not find him particularly annoying. The episodes dealing with his youth (rather than neat sci-fi stuff) were boring, but having a whiz kid on board was fine... by far a more annoying character was the empath, Deanna Troi. She was annoying both in portrayal and in concept: basically a full time psychic on the crew, whose mother was even more annoying than her! At least Crusher's mother was the stellar Dr. Beverly Crusher, whom even Picard could not resist. LOL.

Comment: @Thunderforge Is that better?

Comment: I liked Wesley; he was intelligent, hard working and knew his place at the bottom of the pecking order.

Comment: FWIW, in one of his books, Wheaton provides an explanation why his career crashed in the wake of TNG. According to him, he was sure that his lack of proper acting education would backfire soon enough, so he kind of turned down offers of extending his TNG career in order to get proper acting training. When he was done with that, he had been forgotten already and wouldn't get a foot in the door anymore.

Comment: Weird, I'd always thought that Wesley was pretty well liked, back then and now. Maybe it's because I wasn't _that_ aware of TNG back then (though I did watch it, but missed the first couple of seasons), and I did watch _Big Bang Theory_ where they gushed over him.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

### What did fans think of Wesley?

I'm not sure about the overall fan reaction; I was too young for *Star Trek* during TNG's original run, and very little of that remains easily accessible on the Internet. Fortunately, Google has archived the old Usenet group [alt.ensign.wesley.die.die.die](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/alt.ensign.wesley.die.die.die)<sup>1</sup> which has over 1400 topics (admittedly many, though not most, of which are spambots) and Q-only-knows how many posts, spanning from [October 1990](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.ensign.wesley.die.die.die/XhGznL8Vesw) to [March 2013](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.ensign.wesley.die.die.die/2TWrjzd-yyM). So that's a bit of a clue, anyway.

However, there was definitely enough distaste for the character that Wil Wheaton frequently comments on it. In an interview [reported by TrekMovie.com](http://trekmovie.com/2010/12/08/will-wheaton-wesley-critiques-were-hurtful-talks-nemesis-star-trek-2009/), for example, he said:

> What I was hearing back in the old days were older people who were just sort of predisposed to not like a young character on a show. I think the writers could have navigated around that and made him more relatable, instead of like an idea, but they had a hard time overcoming a lot of that stuff. And when I was a kid it was very hard. It was hard not to take that personally. Kids are awkward. Kids are insecure. I spent 50 hours a week doing Star Trek when I was a kid. That was really my life. To go to conventions back then and have people criticizing me and attacking me personally instead of maybe talking about the writing, it was hurtful.

And on his [website's FAQ](http://www.wilwheaton.net/faq.php#trek):

> **Did it bother you that the fans didn't like Wesley?**
>
> Yes, at the time, it really really did. Imagine being a teenager, trying to handle all the things a teenager has to deal with. Now multiply that times being on a HUGE TV show, and all these people hate you. It was tough.

However, the reaction wasn't completely negative; Wheaton has commented that some people, particularly those who were kids at the time, watched the show *because* of Wesley. [In a blog post](http://wilwheaton.net/2013/12/one-small-part-of-a-pretty-great-life/), he writes:

> [A]s I got older and started to meet more people who were also kids when Next Generation was in its first run, I started to hear these stories from people, about how they had nothing in common with their parents except for Star Trek, and they wouldn't have watched Star Trek together if Wesley hadn't been on the show. I've lost count of the number of people I've met who are now doctors and engineers and scientists because they were inspired by Wesley and Geordi the way our parents’ generation was inspired by Scotty.

### Was Wesley's departure motivated by this dislike?

Unlikely. Wesley wasn't written out of the show *per se*: Wheaton quit. He tells the story [on his website](http://www.wilwheaton.net/faq.php#trek), and it has more to do with how he was treated by the production crew (I've snipped out some of Wheaton's waffling, in the interests of brevity):

> After something like this had happened a lot of times, this was finally the last straw: I had been cast by Milos Foreman to be in Valmont. *[...]* I would have had to sit out the first [TNG] episode of the year, right. That's not a big deal, it's not like I'm the fuckin' Captain, you know. At that point, I was the guy who pushed buttons and said, "Yes, sir!" So, I said to the people on Star Trek, "I need to be written out of this particular episode, because I'm going to do this movie and my film career's going to take off." *[...]* [T]hey said, "We can't write you out because the first episode of the season is all about you. It focuses entirely on your character and it's your story..." So, he said to me, "The story is entirely about you, we can't write you out." I said, "Well, this really sucks, but I'm under contract to you guys and if that's your call and if that's what you say I have to do, I have to do." I had to pass on the movie.
>
> A couple of days before the season was ready to premiere, they wrote me out of the episode entirely. What they were doing was they were sending me a message. The message was, "We own you. Don't you ever try to do anything without us." That was the last straw for me. I called my agents and said, "They don't own me. It's time for me to leave this show, it's time for me to be gone." That's what really pushed me over the edge. It's not worth it anymore. That's why I left.

---

<sup>1</sup> Nod to Rori in comments for pointing me to this

Comment: As an aside, researching for this answer has made me feel really bad for Wil Wheaton. He's been in the business for 35 years, with [a long and varied list of accomplishments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wil_Wheaton#Career), and he [still gets hate for having played Wesley Crusher](http://wilwheaton.net/2009/01/unintended-consequences/). That's just not right.

Comment: I feel like Wil Wheaton, largely redeemed himself in the eyes of most of the fan base after the series ended.  His blog, wilwheaton.net, and his TNG reviews were generally well received.  Plus, he's a huge sci-fi geek, which everyone appreciates.

Comment: Also worth pointing out, at the time there was the usenet group, alt.ensign.wesley.die.die.die, which was popular amongst some subset of fans.

Comment: @N_Soong He's the kind of character that tends to be popular with younger viewers, but less so with older fans of the series; much like Jar Jar, actually, though without the thinly-veiled racism. Personally, having watched TNG as an adult, I didn't dislike him either; not my favourite character, but not as objectionable as some people seem to find him

Comment: +1. Jar-Jar is so annoying not because he's cutesy (so are the Ewoks), or a helpless coward (so is C-3PO), but because he does nothing at all to move the plot along. If Qui-Gon hadn't saved his life, the course of Episode I would be no different. Wesley at least *does* things. IMO, the reason for the Wesley-hate is the character is highly intelligent but has no social skills whatsoever, which strikes a little too close to home for many Trekkies (incluidng my younger self).

Comment: @N_Soong Imagine being the kid who really likes and identifies with Wesley and trying to find fellow fans, when people were selling "Throw Wesley out the Airlock" badges. You'd just keep your mouth shut and feel bad about yourself like a normal teenager.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit No, the reason for the wesley hate is because he was a huge deus ex machine. On a ship with a crew of *literally* thousands, many of whome have decades of experience, it's the teenager who saves the day. This turns the show from a thoughtful sci-fi, into one of those children’s shows where the adults always seem to be inexplicably absent.

Comment: That final rant is, of course, total bullsh!t as he was referring to Season 3 and the opener as aired was, indeed, Wesley-centric.

Comment: @deworde No offence was intended and apologies if it was taken that way!

Comment: @deworde No offence taken, but it certainly explains why you'd never encounter the Lesser Spotted Wesley fan.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not sure I'd describe the Nanites episode as Wesley-centric. He basically stands and listens to Dr Kelso talk about science. From an acting perspective it would certainly seem like he's "Sir Also Appearing".

Comment: @Benubird Well, he had to be pretty brilliant to get there in the first place. The writers had a problem writing a smart character (it's kind of impossible writing a character that's smarter than you), that's all. Even without Wesley, Star Trek as a whole had a whale-load of deus ex machinas and completely ridiculous luck levels - the writers had trouble figuring out "smart" and believable solutions to the problems *all the time*.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In addition to what deworde says, which I half-agree with, I think it's possible we're missing details because Wheaton doesn't provide them - it's likely this either counts as writing him out (because of the very little "presence" the character has overall) or they wrote him out entirely, as he says, then amended the script, which would count as "sending a message". I doubt he'd lie so blatantly to an audience that consists of people who nitpick about these details obsessively, an audience he knows closely enough.

Comment: @Luaan: _"Well, he had to be pretty brilliant to get there in the first place"_ No, he was literally there because his mother lived on the ship. Brilliance or not had absolutely nothing to do with it.

Comment: @ivy_lynx: It's more probable that he was in fact referring to the first episode of the production season (rather than the broadcast season) which was not _The Ensigns of Command_, even if we assume I got the right season. ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I checked that on memory alpha before commenting, but I'm unsure it would be something he wouldn't know about. He was a teenager though, so maybe he just got pissed off and interpreted an unrelated event through the lens of an attitude he had otherwise detected. He would have had an agent though, so I'm still unsure. Overall, I think we're missing too many details on this though I'm inclined to think he would have left either way, since it was really that TNG was unsatisfactory for him and it was standing in the way of his career. (edit - my writing sucks :P).

Comment: @Luaan *"it's kind of impossible writing a character that's smarter than you"*  I think the writers of Sherlock, House, The Imitation Game, The Theory of Everything, and anything that's ever featured Batman or Tony Stark might disagree with that statement.

Comment: @Benubird Completely agree, however he does have one saving grace in *The Game*, where he's so nerdy that he doesn't play -it's the only time he deserves to save the day.

Comment: @deworde Dr. Kelso? Bob Kelso? Damn. That muffin bastard never dies

Comment: As someone who had just started college the year TNG first aired: everyone over the age of 14 hated the character. Not the acting, the writing: WW was never given enough to work with. To be honest, the show didn't really hit its stride until the third season, but Trekkers were just so happy to have something Trek back on the air that they gave it a chance: and the later seasons rewarded them. I don't think TNG really became a juggernaut until "Best of Both Worlds" aired, though.

Comment: @Nerrolken: Re *Sherlock*: Not sure he counts.  At least in the original Doyle books, the general writing technique was (to my eye): come up with a strange situation, provide just exactly enough evidence to rule out all of the more plausible alternatives to that situation, present it out of order and through the lens of a well-meaning but easily misled narrator, and then have your detective miraculously "solve" the problem which you specifically constructed to be solvable.  You're not actually making the character smarter than you are, you're just giving him the answer key.

Comment: The hate was certainly an evolving thing, but ever existing since TNG’s first episodes. Picard’s “Shut up, Wesley” is from S1x13 and gave voice to many fans. Wesley’s character and dislikable features only grew from there over the next three seasons.